# Error when attempting to get values of training dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working on a machine learning project. I have managed to clean the data, one hot encode everything, and separate the independent and dependent variables successfully.

```
data = data.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['initial_list_status', 'addr_state', 'purpose', 'loan_status', 
'verification_status' , 'home_ownership' , 'debt_settlement_flag', 'region', 'Full_Amount'], 
 drop_first=True)

X_trained = data
Y_trained = data.default
X_trained = data.drop(['default'], axis=1,inplace=True)
```

But I cannot get the `values` out of `X_trained`:

```
 X_train = X_trained.values

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the output of `print(X_trained)`?

Comment: you can't use inplace=True if you reassign at the same time, so it should be`X_trained = data.drop(['default'], axis=1)`

Comment: The output of print(X_trained) gives me the out of 'None' but when I attemted to run it again when removing inplace =true it did work. Thank you